# Wireless data transmission more than a bit at a time

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrical-engineering, signal-processing, radio

I'm not that educated in wireless data transmission, but, the basics of frequency modulation and or amplitude modulation are quite basic. Is there any examples of transferring more than a bit at a time, like, a byte or so, 8 bit, encoded similar to how chords are encoded on a piano? (multiple frequencies at once)

Comment: The principle is not restricted to wireless transmission - it applies equally to wired transmission. A sound chord is a good analogy. So is colour mixing, which is a form of what you describe - although our colour perception is considerably less complex, and the eye cannot distinguish colour chords in the way the ear distinguishes sound chords.

Comment: In fact, a very straightforward example of what you're asking for is the DTMF system in telecoms - so-called "tone dialling". Rather than the old morse-code-like system of "pulse dialling", tone dialling creates 2-note chords from 8 fundamental frequencies, and each press of a dialling button transmits 4 bits of information down the line to indicate which button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the signal bandwidth. Any wireless signal will not be a single frequency, but a range of frequencies called the bandwidth. The narrower the bandwidth the more efficient the transmission but the slower the rate of data that will be conveyed. This is why FM radio sounds better than AM radio, the bandwidth is wider so you get more data per second, you get stereo audio. That comes at a cost, which is you need more power to get that signal out. Think of morse code, you get only one thing at a time, either a dit or a dah or a silence. With analogue voice radio you have a band width wide enough for most of the range of the human voice. This is usually limited to 2.7 kHz. With AM you need twice that in the band width, so a bandwidth of about 6 kHz. Any digital voice transmission will do the same, only the signal is digitalised instead of being analogue. High efficiency data transmissions use limited bandwidth and data compression and error correction algorithms to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any examples of transferring more than a bit at a time,

Yes it's very common in modern wireless systems.

One (more-or-less) straightforward method is [quadrature amplitude modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_amplitude_modulation) (QAM). In this scheme, both an in-phase (sine, for example) and a quadratuer (cosine) signal are sent at the same time. Each of these two signals can have its take several different levels in each baud interval (not just two, as in binary phase modulation). The number of different combinations available in a system might be 4 (4-QAM), 16, 32, etc, giving 2, 4, 5, or more bits per symbol transmitted.

Modern wireless systems (4G LTE) use even more complicated modulation schemes such as [orthogonal frequency domain multiple access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_frequency-division_multiple_access) (OFDMA). These not only carry multiple bits per symbol but also manage multiple users sharing a channel.

> like, a byte or so, 8 bit,

Eight bits per symbol requires 256 different possible symbols in the symbol alphabet. This is possible in principle, but tends to be more error prone. With current technology it's usually more economical to transfer fewer (2 or 4 or maybe 6) bits per symbol at a higher symbol (baud) rate.

> encoded similar to how chords are encoded on a piano?

OFDM does in effect do this, but the mechanism to keep the signals on one frequency from interfering with those on another is a bit complicate to explain.

More often, frequency divisions are used to provide separate channels for different data streams to be carried at the same time, rather than to provide more bandwidth to a single data stream (although that would be possible, it just isn't often worth the added complexity and expense).